# Использование ОЗУ Unity3d

Tags: unity3d

от чего может забиваться память при запуске, как билда, так и самого проекта в Unity? Забивается постепенно, пока не забьется полностью. При этом в конкретно этот момент ничего не происходит, ни Update, ни чего-то подобного не используется.

Comment: Есть два способа узнать: гадалка или Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Бесконечные циклы уберите. Например: for(;;) или for с постоянно выполняемым условием, либо цикл while может быть бесконечным. Чаще всего циклы без условия выхода из них становятся причиной загрузки ОЗУ.